# Manage keyboard events on a NSSearchfield without subclassing

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa, keydown, nssearchfield

I have a view with many outlets and a NSSearchfield, i want to do something interesting with the outlets if the user press up arrow in the searchfield. I want to do this without subclassing because i have some problems accesing the outlets from other class

EDIT:
My problem with the outlets is that i can't change their stringvalue from my subclass

```
if ([event keyCode]==126){
        Myclass* c= [[Myclass alloc] init]; // the class that have the outlets
        [c searchf];} //function that something interesting with the outlets
```

Comment: I don't think you can do it without subclassing... What is more precisely your problem with your IBOutlet ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a delegate method you can use:

```
- (BOOL)control:(NSControl *)control textView:(NSTextView *)textView doCommandBySelector:(SEL)command {
    if (control == yourSearchField && command == @selector(moveUp:)) {
        // do custom stuff
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}
```

Comment: I tried your answer with a NSLog but i don't get nothing. I have to do something else apart of change the name of my searchfield. I have never used delegate methods

Comment: Did you set the search field's delegate?

Comment: Only subclasses of `NSControl`.